# Optimize MySQL query to perform efficiently with larger searches

Tags: mysql

I have a query that will let the user search a database of shoes by size. They can select multiple sizes as well as whether the shoe is currently stock.

The query runs OK for smaller searches where there aren't too many sizes/products returned/selected. However, when I search several sizes at the same time, the query takes much longer - and many times it crashes the server.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `#__{vm}_product`.`product_id`, `product_name`, `products_per_row`,
`category_browsepage`, `category_flypage`, `#__{vm}_category`.`category_id`,
`product_full_image`, `product_thumb_image`, `product_s_desc`, `product_parent_id`, 
`product_publish`, `product_in_stock`, `product_sku`, `product_url`, `product_weight`,
`product_weight_uom`, `product_length`, `product_width`, `product_height`, 
`product_lwh_uom`, `product_available_date`, `product_availability`, `#__{vm}_product`.`mdate`,
 `#__{vm} _product`.`cdate`, `#__{vm}_product_attribute`.`attribute_name`, 
`#__{vm}_product_attribute`.`attribute_value`, 
`#__{vm}_product_attribute`.`product_id` 

FROM (`#__{vm}_product`, `#__{vm}_category`, `#__{vm}_product_category_xref`,
`#__{vm}_shopper_group`) 

RIGHT JOIN `#__{vm}_product_attribute` ON `#__{vm}_product`.`product_id` = 
`#__{vm_product_attribute`.`product_id` 
WHERE (`#__{vm}_product_category_xref`.`product_id`=`#__{vm}_product`.`product_id` OR
`#__{vm}product_category_xref`.`product_id`=`#__{vm}_product`.`product_parent_id`) AND ((`#__{vm}_product_attribute`.`attribute_name` = 'Size') AND ((`#__{vm}_product_attribute`.`attribute_value` = '5'))) AND `#__{vm}_product_category_xref`.`category_id`=40 AND `product_publish`='Y' 

GROUP BY `#__{vm}_product`.`product_sku` 
ORDER BY CONVERT(`#__{vm}_product_attribute`.`attribute_value`, SIGNED INTEGER) 
LIMIT 0, 999
```

The output will display the first 24 results.

I believe that there should be a way to make the query not take as long for cases where several sizes are queried. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have indexes on the appropriate columns used in your join conditions? I'd begin looking there. What is your query execution plan showing you? Is there a full table scan? Use indexes to eliminate the full table scan.

Comment: The query would be easier to read if you write all of the `JOIN`s explicitly, not half explicit and half implicit.  It will also make it easier to distinguish between conditions for `JOIN`s and conditions for the search.

Comment: cfeduke: how can I do a query execution plan? what software do you use for that?

Comment: You put EXPLAIN before the query.